# django trailing slash base url

Tags: python, django, mod-wsgi

i'm trailing slash in wsgi for my django application

```
WSGIScriptAlias /rp1 /var/www/reports/app.wsgi
WSGIPythonPath /var/www/reports/
documentroot /var/www/reports/

<Directory /var/www/reports>
    Order deny,allow
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

access to this application by this url : 172.30.12.37/rp1
which best way to add /rp1 prefix to all my url?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't need to do anything special in urls.py. The '/rp1' prefix will automagically be accomodated. If though you are construction redirects from code/templates you do need to make sure you use the proper APIs to construct the URL rather than hardcoding the path. Some settings in Django settings module such as LOGIN_URL do need to explicitly include the prefix though.

So, be more specific about what the actual problem you are having is.